# Gathering schema stats in different schemas

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, schema, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible that gathering schema stats on all the schemas(A,B) helps in running the processes faster in one of the schemas(say B)?

Important point to note here is that the tables/views used in the processes are only present in schema B.

Comment: Not unless there is some dependency on A that you aren't aware of. Why do you think it would help?

Comment: @AlexPoole stats are very useful and needed to be runned, help the processing a lot. There is a gather_schema_stats procedure under dbms_stat, but if the schema is too big then better solution is to call only for the related tables, with the gather_table_stats procedure. Note, this is only then if u have the proper privs

Comment: @Thomas - yes, but the question is whether gathering stats on all schemas (well, including A in this case) will impact processing that is entirely in B. Gathering stats *on B* will help the optimiser and may improve that performance, if they are stale for some reason; stats on objects in unrelated schemas are irrelevant?

Comment: Gathering statistics on objects in schema A will not affect the performance of processes which are entirely dependent on objects in schema B. Those processes which only touch objects in schema B will, of course, be affected when statistics are gathered on schema B. Why would you think that gathering stats on schema A would have any affect on processes which only use objects in schema B?

Comment: I think we dont know enough... assume we are reading tables from schema A, its easy get a stat for it, but if we are creating some "working-tables" in B during the process, and we want to using them, then we need stats for that tables too, like i said before

Comment: @Thomas - the second paragraph in the question says that is not the case - that everything is in one schema. The OP may be wrong of course, hence my first comment, but from what is stated the stats on A have no effect.

Comment: @Everyone - I asked this question since I had noticed the difference between the run time of the process in one of the schemas(B) : When gather stats were done on only B and when they were done on A and B both.Thanks for the help, it might be something else which is affecting the run time.